# Two Sass `@extend`s Conflict

Tags: sass, extend

I have these lines as part of my navigation sass, simplified here:

```
// These lines (66-72) should generate what I want.

.top-nav .nav {
  & > ul {
    a {
      @extend %section-button;
    }
  }
}

// These lines (76-82) prevent the previous code from generating what I want. 
// Delete it to see things work.

.nav {
  & > ul {
    a {
      @extend %section-button;
    }
  }
}
```

When lines 76-82 are deleted, lines 66-72 produce `.top-nav .nav > ul a:hover`, applying the dark grey color to the text on hover. However, when lines 76-82 are allowed to remain, the `.top-nav .nav > ul a:hover` selector is not generated. Why is this?

Changing the order of the selector blocks doesn't help.

I need both blocks because in the `.nav` selector block I override things in `%section-button` that I don't want to be overridden in `.top-nav .nav`.

[Here's the code in a pen, simplified as much as possible while still demonstrating the problem.](http://codepen.io/narthur/pen/ZWvJjO?editors=0100)

Full code:

HTML:

```
<div class="top-nav">
  <nav id="nav" class="nav">
    <ul>
      <li class="page-link"> <a href="/live">Live</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

SCSS:

```
// Colors
$grey-color-dark:  #3f3f3d;
$grey-color-light: lighten($grey-color-dark, 65%);
$blue: #23527c;
$green: #2d5a3a;

// Section Colors

%section-background-color {
  background: $grey-color-dark;
}

%section-text-color {
  color: $grey-color-dark;
}

// Buttons

%button {
  cursor:pointer;
  padding:0 1rem;
  line-height: 2rem;
  height: 2rem;
  display:inline-block;
}

%section-button {
  @extend %button;
  @extend %section-background-color;
  color:$grey-color-light;

  &:hover, &:focus {
    background: $grey-color-light;
    @extend %section-text-color;
  }
}

// navigation

// These lines (66-72) should generate what I want.

.top-nav .nav {
  & > ul {
    a {
      @extend %section-button;
    }
  }
}

// These lines (76-82) prevent the previous code from generating what I want. Delete it to see things work.

.nav {
  & > ul {
    a {
      @extend %section-button;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The code that reproduces the problem *needs to be in your question*.  Links to external sites containing your code are not acceptable.

Comment: @cimmanon Ok. It's a bit long, but I'll edit it in.

Comment: Really?  You need *all* of that code to reproduce the problem??  That's not an [MCVE].

Comment: @cimmanon You should have seen it before. ;) I'll work on editing it down some more when I get a chance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `@extends` when you would want to use a mixin. `@extends` is designed to create groups of classes (and it will compile into one instance), so calling it on both `.top-nav .nav` and `.nav` will create a CSS grouping combining both classes and leading to other unwieldiness. Whereas using a mixin will define two different instances of the `section-button` in the `nav` and `top-nav`.

If you change `%section-button` to `@mixin section-button` and the `@extend %section-button` calls to `@include section-button`, everything should work.

If you are set on using placeholders, you'll need to create several placeholders. But I think that kind of defeats the point of using a placeholder. Or if you're not worried about duplicating code, you could just define the CSS you want inside the `.top-nav` class with a nested `:hover, &:focus` pseudoselector then whatever color you want.

Comment: Yup, everything seems to be working. What's the theory behind this? I still feel like %placeholders should work, though @extend's behavior certainly isn't intuitive for me yet.

Comment: `@extends` is designed to be an option when you want to minimize duplicated CSS. If you are writing a lot of specific class rules, but they share a lot of properties, `@extends` is designed to solve that.